# Clojure backtick expansion

Tags: macros, clojure, backticks

According to the Learning Clojure [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_Clojure/Reader_Macros) backticks are expanded as follows

```
`(x1 x2 x3 ... xn)
```

is interpreted to mean

```
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat |x1| |x2| |x3| ... |xn|))
```

Why wrap concat with seq?  What difference does it make?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how it arose

- `concat` returns a sequence, and
- `seq` returns a sequence with the same content as its sequence argument,

... so `seq` is effectively an identity-op on a `concat`... *except in one circumstance*:

*When `s` is an empty sequence, `(seq s)` is `nil`.*

I doubt that the expansion is correct, since

```
`()
```

... evaluates to

```
()
```

... with type

```
clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList
```

Whereas

```
(seq (concat))
```

... evaluates to

```
nil
```

This suggests that the wrapping call to `seq` is not there.

Comment: This is not true. Empty lists are retained: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L837 - The call to seq is there. It's all over it.

Comment: @LeonGrapentin So far as I can see, my answer is correct and you have confirmed so. My point is that **the proposed expansions** are at fault. As you say, *empty lists are retained*. I agree: *It's there in my answer - as an explicit example.* They would not be if the the expansion in the question or in [@Chiron's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26671421/1562315) prevailed. I haven't a clue how this happens in the compiler. Looking at the code you refer to, the result is `RT.cons(LIST,null)`. This might return `null`, but we **know** it doesn't.

Comment: Look at all the other cases above line 837 - also the else to line 837 - they all wrap a list beginning with seq. This is how it happens in the *reader*.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Nevertheless, the proposed expansions are invalid, for the reasons stated. What is actually wrong *in the answer*?

Comment: The proposed expansions are correct. ``()` is read as `()` because an exception is made for it. In all other cases `seq` is wrapped.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin ... so in the only case in which it would make a substantive difference *to the interpretation of back-tick referred to in the question*, the enclosing `seq` call isn't there?

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin ... so a trifling defect in the reader: generating a redundant enclosing `seq` form - except where it would have some effect - translates into an extremely confusing - because incomplete - explanation. Yet all concerned are doing their best to be clear and accurate.

Comment: The exception is made if an empty list is explicitly read. Otherwise the result of further macroexpansion is always wrapped in seq concat. E. g. ` `(~@())` yields nil.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, it expands to:

```
(macroexpand '`(x1 x2 x3))
(clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote user/x1)) (clojure.core/list    (quote user/x2)) (clojure.core/list (quote user/x3))))

(macroexpand `(x1 x2 x3))
(user/x1 user/x2 user/x3)
```

Why the call `seq` ? Because sequences are corner stones in Clojure philosophy. I recommend you read [Clojure Sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences). Otherwise, I would duplicate it here.

Comment: The call to macroexpand here is entirely useless. `'\`(x1 x2 x3)` evaluates to the same thing.

Comment: @amalloy Yes indeed. I just posted here for more explanation. I can delete it if you suggest so.

Comment: This does not even answer a bit of the question.